# How do I get this coding to work in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, button, input

So I've recently discovered a purely css spoiler code. It works fine in FF (FireFox) but completely spasms out in Google Chrome. Here's the code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.spoiler { background: #000000; color: #ffffff; width: 500px; padding: 40px; }
.spoilerbutton:focus, .spoiler { display: none; }
.spoilerbutton:focus + .spoiler { display: block; }
</style>

<input class="spoilerbutton" type="button" value="Hidden">
<div class="spoiler">
Well hello!
</div>
```

I know it's just CSS, that's because I haven't yet studied jQuery or Javascript. Can anyone fix this so it displays properly in Chrome and isn't just a flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Tested in Chrome 31. FF 24, IE 11

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .spoiler { 
            background: #000000; 
            color: #ffffff; 
            width: 500px; 
            padding: 40px; 
            display: none; 
        }
        .spoilerbutton:focus + .spoiler { display: block; }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <input class="spoilerbutton" type="button" value="Hidden">
        <div class="spoiler">Well hello!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: EDIT: It works great, I was fiddling wrong but it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: nvm my original assumption was wrong I guess, removing it.  current best answer looks more right but leaving the other alternatives.

```
.spoilerbutton:focus, .spoiler { 
    display: none; 
}

.spoilerbutton:hover + .spoiler,
.spoilerbutton:focus + .spoiler { 
    display: block; 
}
```

OR you could do something like this
    http://jsfiddle.net/arevak/g4d54/

OR you could be like reddit 
    http://jsfiddle.net/arevak/LdKSS/